# While statement won't loop followed with if statement

Tags: java

The idea is basic, I want to iterate through a set of bounds.

The way I wanted to do this is by creating a while statement followed by if statements and then increment at the end, and loop.

Try what I like this never makes it to the print statement at the of the while statement, and I can't understand why. (I've tried doing this with a for loop but was unable to figure it out).

Any idea why I can't have an if statement in the while loop?

```
    double a=lend;
    double b=lend+resolution;
    double root;
    System.out.println("Loop starting now.");
    while(b<=rend){
            if(poly(coefs, a)*poly(coefs,b)<0){
                    root = findRoot(coefs, a, b, tolerance);
                    System.out.println(String.format("%.5g%n", root));
            }else if(poly(derivcoefs, a)*poly(derivcoefs, b)<0){
                    root = findRoot(derivcoefs, a, b, tolerance);
                    System.out.println(String.format("%.5g%n", root));
            }else{
                    continue;
            }
            a+=resolution;
            b+=resolution;

            System.out.println("One iteration over, a="+a+", b="+b);
    }
```

Comment: If it never makes it to the last print statement, I'd assume that means it follows through into the last `else` which makes it `continue`

Comment: If the loop is ever entered, then neither `if` nor `else if` are ever true: and the `else` *continues* the loop .. from the loop condition, at the top.

Comment: That really depends on what the rest of your code does.

Comment: I suggest you step through the code in your debugger to see what each line of code is doing.

Comment: What does this `poly` method do?

Comment: You guys are very correct about the continue making the loop start over from the top. I thought continue had it finish the loop then start again from the top. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can have an if statement in a while loop.  Your problem is that the `continue` statement after the final "else" returns control to the beginning of the `while` loop.  So, your three final lines in the While loop -- incrementing a and b and printing "One iteration over"--aren't going to run.  Get rid of that final `else { continue; }` clause.